# how to run a script on ubuntu shutdown when it needs network on

Tags: upstart

I have an upstart script that needs to run on reboot or shutdown, but it needs to access the network to post an http requests and wait for the replies, I tried

```
start on starting rc
```

and

```
start on starting (rc and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
```

but no luck.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work and doesn't answer my question see the last comment in the first answer, it doesn't block the shutdown, I need to block the shutdown until my script finishes

Comment: Problem with blocking shutdown is that the system may assume that the blocker is simply crashed/frozen, and kill it. Shutdown on some devices may assume that the user may be inconvenienced by the lengthy delay (they might miss a bus), or that power is about imminently shut off (low battery)...init has no way to be convinced that your shutdown job is intended behavior. That's why shutdown jobs are discouraged.